# Search only for cells that contain "CAT" and not cells that have "CATION"

Tags: excel, vba

so I have a VBA code that will prompt the selected regions' cells to turn green depending on which word is in cell (1,1). So if I write "CAT" in cell A1, and I have a list of words (cat, cation, brocatium), all of these words turn green. How do I make it so that ONLY cells that ONLY HAVE THE THREE LETTERS "CAT" turn green rather than cells that have "CAT" letters in addition to more letters? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code itself instead of a picture of the code in case others need to copy/paste it.

Comment: So check thar spaces exist either side of “cat”, ie search for “ cat “.

Comment: `If lcase(cell.value) = lcase(Partial_text)` though maybe `Partial_text` is not a good name for that variable.

Comment: Why are you using `InStr()` when you are looking for exact matches?